# What are the parallel branches shorted out in one but not in the other case?

Tags: parallel

Case 1

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMc0lT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Case 2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJGSu.png)</sup>

Why in case 1 only R1 is shorted out. whereas in case 2 both R1 and R2 are shorted out?

Comment: Because of R3 and R4.

Comment: Because in the second one, the short is applied across R2, and in the first one it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the 2nd case, you can "merge" \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ because they are in parallel. Then, going in the way of your logic, if \$R_1\$ is shorted, then the equivalent resistor to \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ is also shorted.

Current is lazy, it rather use a resistanceless path than another one containing resistor to go to a point to another.

- In the first case scenario, there is a path without any resistor to go to point "A" to point "B". But this is not the case for the point "C" and "D" due to \$R_3\$  and \$R_4\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhM6CH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So because R3 and R4, the empty branch, R1, R2 are not technically in parallel. ONly R1 and the empty branch are in parallel. ??

Comment: What I mean is that A, B, C, D are at the same potentiel. because of the lack of R3 and R4 in the circuit

Comment: What does same potential have to do with anything?

Comment: If Va = Vb, because of a shortcut in the circuit, then R1 is useless. Va = Vb = Vc = Vd; Vc = Vd so R2 become useless as well because it got shortcuted

Comment: Could we think of it like this. Current enters the upper branch. The thing that determines if it makes a left turn into R2 is whether there is a lower potential at the other end of R2 branch. Now, assume R2 is shorted out, but that can't be because even if its shorted out, there is R4 and the energy the current carries after going though R4 is lower. So Vd is lower than Vc, so current must go through R2.

Comment: No, if R2 is shorted out, then (V+) and (V-), the voltage source pole, are link together. Since there is no resistor, \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$, R = 0 so the current will increase until fry a fuse or destroy the wire.

Comment: I think you rather take a look to basic electronic course. It will help you more than I can do